# 'unsigned short' array's length in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, count

In Objective C (iOS app), I have

```
unsigned short Alpha[a][b][c];  //this is a global array initialized 
                                //somewhere else. Here, let a=5, b=6, c=7
```

Now in a function I want the length of the array for predefined `a` and `b`.

I tried the following:

```
[Alpha[1][2] length];     //unfortunately no such method exists
[Alpha[1][2] count];      //Warning: Invalid receiver type 'short unsigned int [7]'
```

So I am left with (I guess):

```
(sizeof (Alpha[1][2])) / (sizeof (Alpha[1][2][0]))
```

But as this is a global array, so the function will only get a reference to it.
So, this means it won't give me the desired result or am I wrong?

Any help on this or any other way of doing it would be much appreciated.

Comment: can you tell the interface of the function using it?

Comment: If `a` and `b` predefined, why you can't just use this predefined values?

Comment: `Alpha[x][y]` has `c` elements for all `x` and `y`. You need to keep track of `c`.

Comment: @Cy-4AH here, `c=7` but not for all `a` and `b` there are 7 elements, some of them have less than 7 elements but the maximum is 7. So, predefined values can't be used

Comment: @NicolaMiotto I am so sorry, I didn't get what you mean!!

Comment: to paste the name and parameters of the function, like

`- (void)doStuff:(type)name`
or the c version `int doStuff(type name){`

Answer (score 0):

There is implementation of macro `_countof`

```
#if !defined(_countof)
#if !defined(__cplusplus)
#define _countof(_Array) (sizeof(_Array) / sizeof(0[_Array]))
#else
template <typename _CountofType, size_t _SizeOfArray>
char (*__countof_helper(_CountofType (&_Array)[_SizeOfArray]))[_SizeOfArray];
#define _countof(_Array) sizeof(*__countof_helper(_Array))
#endif
#endif
```

Size values will be:

```
a = _countof(Alpha);
b = _countof(0[Alpha]);
c = _countof(0[Alpha][0]);
```

If you use it in `.mm` then will be used more secure C++ version.